# Cocoa menubar programmatically with NSMenu, how to get standard items "Services", "Hide App", "Hide Others", "Show All" etc

Tags: cocoa, macos-carbon, nsmenu

In decarbonizing I have now come to creating a menubar programmatically using `NSMenu`.

Carbon seems to be so nice to add standard items to the application menu: *Services*, *Hide app*, *Hide Others*, *Show All*, *Quit app*,
and they are even added using the user’s Preferred Language setting in System Preferences’s Language & Region,
so in German *Hide Others* is added as *Andere ausblenden*.

I only had to add the *About* and *Preferences* items.

However, it seems that in Cocoa I have to add these standard items myself,
but how can I find out what *Hide Others* is called in the user’s Preferred Language ?

And what is the Cocoa equivalent of `CreateStandardWindowMenu` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xcode create a new Cocoa application project, it will make a MainMenu.xib that you can examine.  It looks like "Hide Others", "Quit" etc. are just menu items with particular actions assigned, but "Services" seems to have some special magic.  Even if you don't want to present a whole menu bar from a nib, you could load it from a nib and then pick out certain menu items and move them to another menu, rename them or whatever.  Though I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Even if you don't want to localize, you can use a nib.

To address the last part of your revised question, the `NSApplication` object has a `windowsMenu` property, i.e., you could create a menu and say `[NSApp setWindowsMenu: myMenu]`.  But I don't know if that adds items like Bring All to Front or if you must create those yourself.

Comment: I think the e.g. "Hide Others" is some sort of a system menu item, if the user had chosen German as Preferred language in the Language & Region System Preferences, it should be called "Andere ausblenden". How could I possibly know what "Hide Others" is called in all sorts of languages?

Comment: Maybe that kind of automatic renaming happened in Carbon, but it doesn't seem to happen in Cocoa.  As far as I know, if you want it localized, you have to do the work of localizing it.

Comment: @JWWalker "..or if you must create those yourself". Nope, macOS does it for you